# Extracting data from two lists comparing and exporting it to one

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to import a csv file use if info from that run it through each AD user compare the email-addresses and exporting data from ad into a new file.

```
$CATO = Import-Csv -Path "C:\test\testimport.csv"
$adinfo = get-aduser -filter * -properties Name, Office, UserPrincipalName | Select-Object Name, Office, UserPrincipalName

foreach($CATOitem in $CATO){

    $CATOname = $CATOitem.'First Name' + " " + $CATOitem.'Last Name'
    $CATOemail = $CATOitem.Email

    foreach($aditem in $adinfo){

        $adname = $aditem.Name
        $adoffice = $aditem.Office
        $ademail = $aditem.UserPrincipalName

        if($CATOemail -in $ademail){
            $res = $adname, $adoffice, $ademail
            $res | Out-File -FilePath "C:\test\testresult.txt" 
        }

    }

}
```

I'm getting only the last value returned while i want every value (which should be around 500 values)

I'd like a result in a csv file with the colums "NAME" "OFFICE" and all the values underneath that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although adding `-Append` will make your code work, it is really quite inefficient code.

Also, why use a plain text file as output, when you have objects to write instead of a CSV file?

Try below:

```
$CATO = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\yclaeys\Documents\PSScripts\Michel script CATO\vpnusers.csv"
# get an array of Email addresses from the CSV (remove empty fields)
$CATOemail = $CATO.Email | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }

# get users with UserPrincipalName corresponding to the `Email` column in your CSV file
# and export as proper new CSV file
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name, Office, UserPrincipalName | 
    Where-Object { $CATOemail -contains $_.UserPrincipalName } |
    Select-Object Name, Office, UserPrincipalName |
    Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\yclaeys\Documents\PSScripts\Michel script CATO\res.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Use key `-Append` in `Out-file` to add info, without it you rewrite file each time.

Comment: to add colums better way is use `export-csv` it has delimiters